# How to push object into array angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular8

i am getting below example data in `this.selectedParameterContext.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
deleteAllContextData(data) {
const newSelectedParameterContext = {
  'records': []
};   
this.selectedParameterContext.records.forEach(function (record) {
  const newSelectedParameterValues = [];
  record.values.forEach(function (parameter, parameterIndex) {
    const isValid = data.data.values.find(function (item) {
      return parameter.value === item.value && parameter.label === item.label;
    });
    if (isValid) {
      newSelectedParameterValues.push(parameter);
    }
  });     
  newSelectedParameterContext.records.push({ ...record, 'values': newSelectedParameterValues });
}); 
this.selectedParameterContext = newSelectedParameterContext;
```

}

Comment: No its creating wrong array and even context and values objects are replicating

Comment: I want the pasted expected output from above code

Comment: please share the input paramter for deleteAllContextData function.

Comment: Here is the data which i am passing in deleteAll function.
const data = {
    "action": "deleteAll",
    "data": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "b",
          "label": "b"
        },
        {
          "value": "c",
          "label": "c"
        }
      ]
    }
  };